# Outlook 365 with multiple OST for shared mailboxes

Tags: microsoft-outlook, script, exchange

Background:  At work I've users with multiple shared mailboxes (some with over 15) and this causes over bloated OST file.

Solution needing converted to a script to be run on user's computer (assume they don't have local admin rights).  I searched but can't find a solution. TIA.

1. list of shared mailboxes user is connected to in a text file.
2. close/exit outlook then delete existing OST file.
3. box popup asking for user's name and password (masked with *).
4. Uncheck the box download shared mailbox (not sure if this is needed)
5. read text file line by line to add additional mailboxes with users credentials from step 2.
6. restart outlook

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems.

Comment: This is not how Office365 works. If all mailboxes are in one OST file and the OST file is growing too large, then either uncheck the checkbox download shared mailboxes, or remove the Full Access flag on those mailboxes from the admin console and manually add them in outlook yourself. Not gonna be possible with a script.

Comment: If you have too much email for your OST file, archive older email. This is the proper way to manage OST files.  (Been there, done that).

Answer (score 0):

According my search, if you add another user's shared mailbox or shared folder to your profile, then all the folders in the shared mailbox to which you have access are downloaded to your local cache by default. So the ost file size will be larger,

[image]
To control the size of the OST file, here are some methods for your reference:

1. The **Compact Now** option is the way to reduce the OST file size in Exchange Online and this might improve performance.
   **File > account settings > account settings > change > more settings > advanced**, then click **outlook data file settings > compact now**  > ok.
2. [Disable caching of shared folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/outlook/troubleshoot/data-files/by-default-shared-mail-folders-are-downloaded-in-cashed#:%7E:text=When%20you%20use%20a%20Group%20Policy%20to%20disable%20this%20setting%2C%20the%20following%20registry%20key%20value%20is%20configured%20on%20Outlook%20clients%3A)

Hope above may help you!